# Problemas com diretório

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Estou tentando realizar a leitura de um arquivo .html mas não consigo obter o caminho deste arquivo. Já utilizei `Environment.GetCurrentDirectory()` e `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` mas não obtive êxito. Abaixo segue código que estou tentando atualmente, mas ele tenta recuperar o caminho de execução da solução.

`var foo = File.ReadAllText(@"~/EmailTemplate/email.html");`

Com este código, obtenho o seguinte erro:

Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'C:......\bin\Debug~\EmailTemplate\email.html'.

Comment: Qual tipo de aplicação? Web, WCF, WebService, WinForms???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de onde você quer pegar o diretório atual deve fazer isto:

```
using System.Console;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"EmailTemplate/email.html"));
        WriteLine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"EmailTemplate/email.html"));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/V6Vuig). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gXCfwv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Directory.cs).

A primeira forma com [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_Directory_GetCurrentDirectory) pega o diretório corrente que a aplicação estiver acessando. Ela pode ser o mesmo diretório da aplicação ou não. Você tem que ver se é isto que deseja.

Se quer garantir que pegue o local onde a aplicação está tem que usar a segunda forma que pega o [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_Location).

Se o critério é outro para descobrir o diretório que deve ser usado como base, tem que descobrir qual é o critério e escolher o método que retorne a informação adequada. Se nenhuma destas duas resolver o problema porque a base é diferente, dê mais informações na pergunta para eu colocar uma nova opção.

Note que o [`Path.Combine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_) é usado para transformar as duas partes do caminho em um caminho válido e completo.

Como curiosidade [`Environment.CurrentDirectory()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Environment_CurrentDirectory) produz exatamente o mesmo que `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. Na verdade um chama o outro.

Comment: Do jeito que você colocou, se aplicação dele for um executável, o `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` não irá retornar o caminho do `.exe`? Ai no `Path.Combine` não irá ocorrer erro?

Comment: @RichardDias até onde eu sei não, você tem alguma informação que mostre isto? Eu não posso garantir. A aplicação é um executável e parece estar funcionando conforme demostrado. Não estou afirmando que não tenha alguma situação que isto falhe, se você souber e puder demonstrar, seria interessante para todos aprendermos. Até onde eu sei ele pega só a parte do diretório para fazer a combinação, então se tem um arquivo que ele está se referenciando não importa, ele sabe fazer a limpeza e pegar só o que interessa.

Comment: Falei isso pois segundo o exemplo que eu postei, utilizando um executável, ele retornava o caminho do arquivo `.exe`, por isso usei um `FileInfo` para pegar o nome do diretório onde o `.exe` está sendo executado. Estava fazendo isto ainda ontem, e esta foi a solução que eu encontrei para resolver uma situação semelhante.

Comment: @RichardDias acho que agora entendi o que você está dizendo, fiz uma alteração que acho que resolve a questão.

Answer (score 1):

Kleyton, esta variável do sistema irá pegar o diretório onde a aplicação está executando, por isto ela vai apresentar um comportamento um pouco diferente na versão de release do que em debug.

No seu caso, vejo que é interresante você pegar o endereço do Projeto/Publicação.

Você pode acessá-lo usando:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o seguinte:

```
var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
//No exemplo citado presumo que seja um executável
var pastaExe = fi.Directory.FullName;

var caminhoArquivo = System.IO.Path.Combine(pastaExe, "EmailTemplate/email.html");
```

Acredito que isto irá suprir a sua necessidade e você não deverá mais se preocupar com o caminho do arquivo.